# What are the actual differences in binaries made with Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I presume that the binaries made with VS2012 are better, using newer system calls, using 64 bit arch specific commands, etc, but I have no idea if this is actually true.  Can anyone elaborate on the differences?

Note: the reason I ask is because apachelounge provides builds of both and I was told that if VS2012 is at all better I should make a build of our software with that build of apache.

Comment: If you want an excruciatingly technical report on how the compiler (for which language???) in VS2010 is different from the one in VS2012, this is certainly not the place to get it.

Comment: @Jon: Apache is written in C.  Aside from that I don't understand why asking a question about this is a problem.  On the about page it specifically mentions "Software Development Tools".  Also, for what it's worth, a link to a Microsoft article would be sufficient.